# How to solve this drag and drop using pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve a problem related to drag and drop TEST.

Please take a look at the image below. There are 3 columns where each contains 3 small
boxes of different colors. These boxes are draggable means they can be dragged and dropped
between any of the columns but 2 following conditions must match:
● Two same colored boxes can't be on the same column. As you can see, the first and
second columns each contain a green box. So you can't drag the green box from the
first column to the second but it's draggable to the third column.
● The drag and drop should only be limited to the column area. If you drag a box and
drop it somewhere which is not a column, it should go back to the column where it
was dragged from

[image: Click to see the image]

Here is my code which failed to track the same color identification...

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var choice = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
var dragItem = null;

console.log(p)

for (var i of p) {
  i.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  i.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
  console.log(i)
}

function dragStart() {
  dragItem = this;
  setTimeout(() => this.style.display = "none", 0);
}

function dragEnd() {
  setTimeout(() => this.style.display = "block", 0);
  dragItem = null;
}

for (j of choice) {
  j.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  j.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  j.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  j.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}





function Drop() {
  this.append(dragItem)
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

function dragLeave() {}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>drag & drop</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Rank in order as your choice</h1>
  <section>
    <div class="choice">
      <p id="green" draggable="true">Green</p>
      <p id="orange" draggable="true">Orange</p>
      <p id="purple" draggable="true">Purple</p>
    </div>
    <div class="choice">
      <p id="yellow" draggable="true">Yellow</p>
      <p id="green" draggable="true">Green</p>
      <p id="orange" draggable="true">Orange</p>
    </div>
    <div class="choice">
      <p id="pink" draggable="true">Pink</p>
      <p id="skyblue" draggable="true">Skyblue</p>
      <p id="purple" draggable="true">Purple</p>
    </div>


  </section>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Make This Drag n Droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396900/how-to-make-this-drag-n-droppable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Drop function check if target element has dragged element ID

```
function Drop() {
  if (this.querySelector('#' + dragItem.id)) {
    return;
  }
  this.append(dragItem)
}
```

snippet

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var choice = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
var dragItem = null;

//console.log(p)

for (var i of p) {
  i.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  i.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
  i.style.background = i.id;
  //console.log(i)
}

function dragStart() {
  dragItem = this;
  setTimeout(() => this.style.display = "none", 0);
}

function dragEnd(ev) {
  setTimeout(() => this.style.display = "block", 0);
  dragItem = null;
}

for (var j of choice) {
  j.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  j.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  j.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  j.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}

function Drop() {
  if (this.querySelector('#' + dragItem.id)) {
    return;
  }
  this.append(dragItem)
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

function dragLeave() {}
```

```css
.choice {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 5px;
}

.choice p {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rank in order as your choice</h1>
<section>
  <div class="choice">
    <p id="green" draggable="true">Green</p>
    <p id="orange" draggable="true">Orange</p>
    <p id="purple" draggable="true">Purple</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
    <p id="yellow" draggable="true">Yellow</p>
    <p id="green" draggable="true">Green</p>
    <p id="orange" draggable="true">Orange</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
    <p id="pink" draggable="true">Pink</p>
    <p id="skyblue" draggable="true">Skyblue</p>
    <p id="purple" draggable="true">Purple</p>
  </div>

</section>
```